# In spark SQL/Hive QL, How to select a column that is a reserved keyword

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have a column named 'count'
this is easy as flipping to select in LINQ:

```
rdd.select('count)
```

but hard to select in SQL, so far all the answer I've found are "illegal name, don't use".
How could it be that hard to implement a keyword escaping mechanism?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you wrap the column name in backticks, things might work out. For example:

```
SELECT date, `last`, open, high, low, volume, change FROM timeseries
```